STSでSpringFrameWorkを使いたい
STS4でSpringFrameWorkのプロジェクトを作成したいのですが、SpringFrameWorkのテンプレートが見当たらず、苦戦している状況です。
ＳＴＳ４ではSpringFrameWorkを使うことはできないのでしょうか。
またどうしたらいいいですか。

公式リファレンス(本文末尾リンク)では Spring Initializr が案内されています。
これで Spring Boot ベースの Starter プロジェクトを作成できます。
Webサービスとしては https://start.spring.io/ , STS4のメニューでは File >> New >> Spring Starter Project から実行できます。
(やってることはどちらも同じです)

Getting Started - Spring Framework Documentation
Create New Spring Boot Projects - Spring Tool Suite 4 Wiki

